# How to get the zeros of the given equation using fzero in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have the following function that I wish to solve using fzero:

```
f = lambda* exp(lambda^2)* erfc(lambda) - frac {C (T_m - T_i)}/{L_f*sqrt(pi)}
```

Here, `C`, `T_m`, `T_i`, and `L_f` are all input by the user.

On trying to solve using `fzero`, MATLAB gives the following error.

```
Undefined function or variable 'X'.
```

(where `X` are the variables stated above)

This error is understandable. But is there a way around it? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is answered to the best of my understanding after reading your question as it's not really clear what you are exactly trying and what you want exactly.
Posting the exact lines of code helps a big deal in understanding(as clean as possible, remove clutter). If then the output that matlab gives is added it becomes a whole lot easier to make sure we answer your question properly and it allows us to try it out. Usually it's a good idea to give some example values for data that is to be entered by the user anyway.

First of to make it a function it either needs a handle.
Or if you have it saved it as a matlab file you generally do not want other inputs in your m file then the variable.
So,

```
function [out]=yourfun(in)
constants=your values; %you can set a input or inputdlg to get a value from the user
 out= something something, your lambda thingy probably; %this is the equation/function you're solving for
end
```

Now since that is not all that convenient I suggest the following

```
%declare or get your constants here, above the function makes it easier
syms lambda
f = lambda* exp(lambda^2)* erfc(lambda) - frac {C (T_m - T_i)}/{L_f*sqrt(pi)};
hf=matlabFunction(f); %this way matlab automatically converts it to a function handle, alternatively put @(lambda) in front
fzero(hf,x0)
```

Also this matlab page might help you as well ;)